# How to bind data from view dropdown list to controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have simple project to do. Adding employee to specific task. My problem is sending selected employee from form to database. All the other info, like title or deadline are in the database but employee is not.

Here is part of my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(AddAssignmentViewModel addAssignmentRequest)
{
    var assignment = new Assignment()
        {
            taskID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            title = addAssignmentRequest.title,
            description = addAssignmentRequest.description,
            assignee = addAssignmentRequest.assignee,
            dueDate = addAssignmentRequest.dueDate,
        };

    await dataContext.Assignments.AddAsync(assignment);
    await dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

private List<SelectListItem> GetEmployees()
{
    var lstEmployees = new List<SelectListItem>();
    List<Employee> employees = dataContext.Employees.ToList();

    lstEmployees = employees.Select(e => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = e.employeeID.ToString(),
            Text = e.fullName
        }).ToList();

    var defItem = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = "",
            Text = "---Select Employee---"
        };

    lstEmployees.Insert(0, defItem);

    return lstEmployees;
}
```

Here is the view model:

```
public class AddAssignmentViewModel
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Employee assignee { get; set; }
    public DateTime dueDate { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view:

```
<form method="post" action="Add">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="title">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="description">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Assignee</label>
        <select asp-for="assignee" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.assignee"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Due Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" asp-for="dueDate">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I open localhost, there is list of all employees that I added in database and I can select one of them, but when I click submit, field for employee in database is null. Other fields are okay.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hows your `ViewBag.assignee` is loading? In addition, what are you passing within `Employee assignee` could you explain few more details?

Answer (score 0):

> I have simple project to do. Adding employee to specific task. My
> problem is sending selected employee from form to database. All the
> other info, like title or deadline are in the database but employee is
> not

Actually, your [model bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) are incorrect because, you have defined your AddAssignmentViewModel with property assignee which is a type of Employee class. But while you are populating your dropdown value its a type of [SelectListItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) that keeps data as Text and Value pairs. Thus, it doesn't matched with the [Model Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#model-binding-simple-and-complex-types) and you are getting null assignee in your controller. As you can see below:

[image]

[image]

> When I open localhost, there is list of all employees that I added in
> database and I can select one of them, but when I click submit, field
> for employee in database is null. Other fields are okay

As you can see the debugging results, while you are hitting submit button your dropdown value which is has populated with text and value and assignee has mapped with it but within your viewModel its a type of POCO class consequntly, your value has lost and ended up with null assignee data.

Root Cuase:

Main reason for your null data is Assignment POCO class where you have referenced Employee class which is incorrect. As its a another class which should be referred as [Foreign key constraint name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#foreign-key-constraint-name) that's is employeeID but you have directly lined the class which causing the issue. You could have done this the way you are doing if your dropdown were  a type of Strongly type class rather than a SelectListItem type.

**Solution:**

Update Model:

```
public class Assignment
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid taskID { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId{ get; set; }
        public DateTime dueDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Update View Model:

```
public class AddAssignmentViewModel
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public int assignee { get; set; }
        public DateTime dueDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Update Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Add(AddAssignmentViewModel addAssignmentRequest)
        {
            var assignment = new Assignment()
            {
                taskID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                title = addAssignmentRequest.title,
                description = addAssignmentRequest.description,
                EmployeeId = addAssignmentRequest.assignee,
                dueDate = addAssignmentRequest.dueDate,
            };

            await _context.Assignments.AddAsync(assignment);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#model-binding-simple-and-complex-types) and  [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#model-binding-simple-and-complex-types)